# Opposite of CTRL+D in Sublime Text 2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

In Sublime Text 2, one may extend selection to include the next occurence of the current selection with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I often find myself pressing this one too many times, necessitating I clear selection and start again, albeit more carefully.

Is there an opposite shortcut that removes the most recently added selection from the current selection?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

> Quick Add Next
>
> To add the next occurrence of the current word to the selection, use
>   Quick Add Next, which is bound to Ctrl+D on Windows and Linux, or
>   Command+D on OS X.
>
> Again, if you go too far, use Undo Selection (Ctrl+U, or Command+U on
>   OS X) to step backwards.

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Comment: And to skip a match use Crtl+K+D